# Efficiently modify list in Python

Tags: python, performance, list, python-3.x, mutable

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to modify a list in python using only the standard library. The two best alternatives I've found for my situation are

```
s = [i + k for i in l[a:b]]
l[a:b] = s
maxx = max(maxx, max(s))
```

and

```
for i in range(a,b):
    l[i] += k
maxx = max(maxx, max(l[a-1:b]))
```

The first version is fast but can use a lot of memory, the second takes twice as long but used half the memory.

The full code is similar to this

```
from random import randint
maxx = 0
n = 1000000
m = 11111
l = [0 for i in range(n)]
for i in range(m):
   a = randint(0, n-2)
   b = a + randint(1, n-a)
   k = randint(1, 99999)
   s = [i + k for i in l[a:b]]
   l[a:b] = s
   maxx = max(maxx, max(s))
```

Comment: Guess the builtin [map](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map) does the thing you are looking for. Do a time bench to check which one is faster. `map(lambda x: f(x), l[a: b])`

Comment: @HelloWorld Tried it and it's slower that both by 30% because of the need to iterator over the iterable as far as I can tell. I does us far less memory though.

Comment: in my testing, map is actually not that great performance-wise (at least, it's usually slower than the equivalent list comprehension version); in addition, it always creates a list (even if the output is None) so it does consume memory too.

Comment: not sure if that's your real code, but note that for associative properties (like simple addition), `max([i+k for i in list])` should equal `max(list) + k`...

Comment: Is it really the list you are worried about or the max

Comment: @jcfollower I am using this to learn about Python performance.

Comment: You can certainly get better performance by writing this several different ways. But for high-performance manipulation of numerical lists (and matrices), your biggest win would be switching from stock Python lists to more efficient vector data structures, such as [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), [numpy.array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), or [pandas.Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html). There is a learning curve, to be sure, but they *dramatically* accelerate math on large datasets.

Comment: my experience is similar to yours - list comprehensions are almost always the fastest - but on my system, the in-place modify (for loop) is only about 1.5x as long (510 uS vs. 782uS) (for [a,b) about 10% of the total). in practice, how much this matters depends on the actual modification you are doing (is it an expensive function call, or simple math, etc)? also.. you don't need to do the maxx in the loop, you could just do it at the end (it won't save that much though).

Comment: @JonathanEunice I tried initializing `l = array('Q', [0 for i in range(n)])` and leaving everything else the same, there was no change in performance. I expect numpy is significantly faster buy I'm limited to only the standard library.

Comment: on your second option, have you tried using `xrange` instead of `range`.  (`xrange` doesn't build an actual list of numbers, but `range` does)

Comment: @jcfollower OP seems to be using / asking about Python 3, so `range` is the equivalent of what `xrange` is in Python 2.

Comment: @nash The `'Q'` datatype for `array.array` is very long. I would use one of the shorter integer types, such as `'i'` or `'L'`.   Keep in mind that the way this loop is structured, with a large number of random-length spans, one run to the next may be doing much more or much less work. To control for that, you'd need to pre-choose the spans then choose the same ones for each benchmark run. Otherwise you're likely to get widely varying, and not always representative, results.